# How to determine wrong data type

Tags: python

I use the following to see if the data is an integer, if not it tells me. Is there a way to determine which one is incorrect so can change it or would i have to create the same loop for every item?

```
while i_input == True:
    try:
        i_pointstarget=int(pointstarget.get())
        i_ap1=int(ap1.get())
        i_ap2=int(ap2.get())
        i_ap3=int(ap3.get())
        i_ap4=int(ap4.get())
        i_ap5=int(ap5.get())
        i_ap6=int(ap6.get())
    except ValueError:
        i_input=False
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: ... Have you considered writing a separate function to convert?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't need to convert it i just need to locate which one is wrong

Comment: If you don't need to convert it then how come you keep calling `int()` each time?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because I want the variable to be a int, i was using this to then detect if it's not an int however it doesn't tell you which one isn't an int. At least I think that's what it is doing - i'm new and not very good :)

Comment: Add some sample input and out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to convert to `int` (btw `int(1.23)` works, returning `1`) you can also use [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) like

```
import numbers
def is_integral(n): # actually not checking for int but also other int-equivalents
    return isinstance(n,numbers.Integral)
```

if you want to check if you have a number which can loslessy be converted to an integral number (like `int`) you can do

```
import numbers
def exact_integral(n): # check if n can be exactly represented as an integer
    return isinstance(n,numbers.Complex) and n==round(n.real)
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the type of a variable you can use `isinstance(variable_name, int)`, this will return the Boolean value.